# How to query nested documents in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I am very new to database and MongoDB. I tried to stored financial statment information in the database with each document representing a company.

I have created a nested documents (maybe not a good way), like the following diagram. the outest level contains Annual statement, Basic info, Key Map, and Interim Statement. And within Annual statement, there are different dates. And within dates, we have different types of statements (INC, BAL, CAS), and then the inner level contains the real data.
[image]

My question is how can I query the db to give me all documents contain 2017 statements (for example)?

The year is now formated as YYYY-MM_DD. but I only wants to filter YYYY.

Comment: are INC properties fixed fields name (SREV,RTLR, ...) . Do you know them all at advance?

Comment: Yes. I have a Map that tells me what fields name stand for. That's actually stored in the "Key Map".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly discourage to use variable (date, INC here) as field name. It will be (much more) harded to query, update, you cannot use index. So it's a very bad idea in most of case, even if it can be 'acceptable' (but bad practice) in case of a few numbers of static values (INC, BAL, CAS).

My advice will be to change your schema for something easier to use like for example :

```
[
  {
    "annual_statement": [
        { "date": ISODate("2017-12-31"),
          "INC":{
              "SREV": 1322.5,
              "RTLR": 1423.4,
              ...
            },
          "BAL":{...},
          "CAS":{...}
        },
      {   "date": ISODate("2017-12-31"),
          "INC":{
              "SREV": 1322.5,
              "RTLR": 1423.4,
              ...
            },
          "BAL":{...},
          "CAS":{...}
        }
    ]
  }
]
```

To query this schema, use the following :

```
db.collection.find({
  "annual_statement": {
    $elemMatch: {
      date: {
        $lt: ISODate("2018-01-01"),
        $gte: ISODate("2017-01-01"),

      }
    }
  }
})
```

Will return you whole documents where at least on date is in 2017.

Adding projection like following will return you only matching annual statements :

```
db.collection.find({
  "annual_statement": {
    $elemMatch: {
      date: {
        $lt: ISODate("2018-01-01"),
        $gte: ISODate("2017-01-01"),

      }
    }
  }
},
{
  "annual_statement": {
    $elemMatch: {
      date: {
        $lt: ISODate("2018-01-01"),
        $gte: ISODate("2017-01-01"),

      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Why sometimes we use list, and sometimes dict?

Can I do "annual_statement":{ } instead of [ ]

Comment: Question of logic : you have a list of statements, you use array as statements. And using an object (or dict) force you to use variable for field names, and don't forget you cannot query on field names, but only on field values.

Comment: Now, I have modified the schema. And how can I query all statement in year 2017 for example?

Answer (score 0):

Use $exists (note I'm using python - pymongo driver syntax below - yours may differ)
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/

Example: Find all "2017" "INC" records, by company.

```
year_exists=db.collection.find({'Annual.2017-12-31': {'$exists':True}})

for business in year_exists:
     bus_name = business['BasicInfo']['CompanyName']
     financials_INC = business['Annual']['2017-12-31']['INC'])
     print(bus_name, financials_INC)
```

Comment: This would work but it is not what the OP is asking ... the requirement is to "search" by just "YYYY".

Comment: thanks for the input Akrion. I was assuming that "filter" statement was irrelevant since the reports are annual so the key could be anything with the year included. I was actually trying to answer the question vs. explain how to structure the data better. I should have probably asked for clarification. thx again.